# who created/coded ext4lazyinit for ext4?

Tags: linux, debian, ext4

I have been trying to figure out who the author of ext4lazyinit ? I tried searching on lwn.net, didn't get anything. I tried using -

```
┌─[shirish@debian] - [/usr/share/doc/linux-image-4.9.0-1-amd64] - [10080]
└─[$] zless changelog.linux.gz
```

I tried searching for pattern inside the changelog but found no mention on it on the changelog even though the changelog.linux.gz goes all the way to 2005.

Can anybody share/explain where can I get more details please ?

Comment: can somebody share why the hammering ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lukas Czerner - i used google.

https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=bfff68738f1cb5c93dab1114634cea02aae9e7ba